# net-ssh2 installation in linux

Tags: perl, ssh, openssl, net-ssh

I am trying to install Net-SSH2 in linux server and it is asking for lots of dependencies.
I installed both libssh2 and openssl, but still it throws the follwoing error.

```
/opt/script/Net-SSH2-0.52/assertlibcssKKx3q: error while loading shared libraries: libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
wrong result: 'ssh2'
```

Can someone tell me whats happening here?

Please find below the installation log

```
[root@vm Net-SSH2-0.52]# perl Makefile.PL
Subroutine checklibs redefined at inc/Module/Install/CheckLib.pm line 11.
Subroutine assertlibs redefined at inc/Module/Install/CheckLib.pm line 25.
Subroutine _author_side redefined at inc/Module/Install/CheckLib.pm line 39.

The libssh2 library is required by this module.  If you don't have it, you can
download it from http://www.libssh2.org; you may also need OpenSSL, which can be
obtained from http://www.openssl.org, or libgcrypt, which can be obtained from
http://www.gnupg.org.

Debian:   sudo aptitude install libssh2-1-dev
OpenSUSE: sudo zypper in libssh2-1 libssh2-devel

You can pass your libssh2 lib and include dirs on the command line. E.g.:

    perl Makefile.PL lib=$HOME/libssh2/lib inc=$HOME/libssh2/include

To build with libgcrypt instead of OpenSSL, pass 'gcrypt' as a parameter to
Makefile.PL, e.g.:

    perl Makefile.PL gcrypt

If you want to build on Windows, see the file BUILDING.WIN32 in the
distribution.

/opt/leo/perlscript/Net-SSH2-0.52/assertlibjmyXurmJ: error while loading shared libraries: libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
wrong result: 'ssh2'
```

Comment: This smells like Net-SSH2 was not installed correctly. Provide the full log of the installation attempt.

Comment: I have attached the installation logs.

Comment: I need more information. Which Linux distribution is that? Did you install libssh2 and its development/headers files through the package manager, or manually? - Please provide the installation steps in detail that you mentioned near the top of your question.